# Using Webkit to Style Interfaces?

Tags: webkit

I'm really new to programming, and creating programs. Recently I was browsing around iTunes folder and I saw a .css file. I opened it up and saw a lot of -webkit styles to style there interface.

Can I use webkit to style languages interfaces that are coded such as C++, .NET, Python, ETC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Webkit is opensource, the answer is: yes, you can. There are however things to note:
* There are no precompiled binaries to try out - you have to compile it yourself
* There are various implementations (so called "ports") that make Webkit available on various platforms. If you want a high stability, you have got to choose GTK, Qt or Apple ports. These are crossplatform and well tested but they have a disadvantage of low configurability and they depend on heavy frameworks that you must include.
* If you choose any other port, you realize that it's either not crossplatform or has been abandoned (for example the Clutter port)
* You may also choose an "unofficial" port like the [OWB](http://www.sand-labs.org/owb). It is however not much supported and especially the Windows compatibility sucks.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) has a nice article about Webkit.
If I haven't scared you much, you can head to http://www.webkit.org and find the solution that fits your needs.

If you don't necessarily need C++ port, try these links:
http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/
http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/